# Estou tentando ler um json e converter em um arquivo xlsx com pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Estou tentando especificar quais colunas eu quero pegar e transformar, mas todas são convertidas.

```
{
  "livros": [
    {
      "imgCapa": "https://s3.novatec.com.br/capas/9788575226834.jpg",
      "descricao": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>",
      "titulo": "Primeiros passos com a linguagem Rust",
      "pgAutores": {
        "pgAutor1": "autores/jose-manzano.php"
      },
      "autores": {
        "autor1": "José Augusto N. G. Manzano"
      },
      "categoria": "Programação",
      "isbn": "978-85-7522-683-4",
      "ano": "2018",
      "paginas": "312",
      "preco": 69,
      "estoque": "Disponível também em formato ebook"
    }]}
```

---

```
with open('db.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
#TRANSFORM
    dados = pd.json_normalize(data=data['livros'], 
                            
                            meta=['livros',['livros','titulo'],
                                    ['livros', 'autores','autor1']] )
    

dados = dados.rename(columns={
    'descricao': 'Descrição',
    'titulo': 'Titulo',
    'categoria': 'Categoria',
    'paginas': 'Paginas',
    'estoque': 'Estoque',
    'autores.autor1': 'Autor',
    'preco': 'Preço'
})
#LOADING
dados.to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente você só renomeia as colunas mas não faz nenhum filtro de quais devem ir para o excel

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("db.json", 'r') as f:
    arquivo_json = json.load(f)

colunas = {
    'descricao': 'Descrição',
    'titulo': 'Titulo',
    'categoria': 'Categoria',
    'paginas': 'Paginas',
    'estoque': 'Estoque',
    'autores.autor1': 'Autor',
    'preco': 'Preço'}
```

Aqui, após renomear as colunas é feito um filtro pelos items do dicionário colunas, pegamos o valor e não a chave:

```
df = (pd
      .json_normalize(arquivo_json["livros"])
      .rename(columns=colunas)[[item[1] for item in colunas.items()]])
```

Salvando o arquivo

```
df.to_excel("data.xlsx", index=False)
```